# Answers are shown twice under answer

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I just experienced something strange, you can have a look at the picture:

http://imagesup.net/?di=1137001123714

For some reason I have had an orange bar at the top, it looked like my java was not enabled, telling me that there were new answer and i could open them clicking there. Additionally I had the "default" grey bar under the answer with "2 new answers to this question".

Is this a bug or something? I didn't change any settings, may it be because of the connection?

Comment: @returnPhaDaPhunk you cannot see it, it was just fine after refreshing, i've experienced this a couple of time. Anyway it is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16859108/how-to-add-a-line-break-into-a-mailto-link-that-is-being-encoded-with-phps-rawu/16859229#16859229

Comment: @MartijnPieters Looks like an answer to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just encountered a race condition, where the AJAX notifier (the big orange bar) got there before the websocket data did. You got the answers from two different methods.

Reload and it'll all look fine again.